Compiling pre-existing VC++ Solution, Edited VC Project Missing Log4CplusUD.lib
So I am compiling a project, several actaully, which require Log4CPlus based on the errors I got. I included the proper directory in the additional include directories in the C/C++ tab in the properties menu.
So based on what I read, and from compiling, my latest issue is I am missing the log4cplusUD.dll, which apparently is meant to be compiled and built by the system. Following the instictions in the 'Installation' file which is just text, it says to './configure' first. As soon as I do, I get the most common error:
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Changing 'configure' file to a batch file, then running 'configure' or './configure', results in a series of errors which essentially begin to read the file by text and states they are again are not operable commands (obviously), same error as before.
Context:
Log4CPlus Version - 2.1.1 (Not 100% sure what version was used when the project I am compiling was built)
Windows 10/11, 64x architecture
I am using several other dependencies, such as boost, Google Protocol Buffers, Xerces Apache, HDF5, etc. I did not do anything to these such as building them, just included the proper directories to include the proper header files.
The main goal is to make this solution compile, which has atleast 4 dozen VC++ projects. If anyone has any advice, videos, forums, etc. they can point me to for understanding what I may be missing to make this work it is very much accepted.
The current issue is the missing log4cplusUD.dll which apparently has to be built. But I can't build it.... So any advice on getting this built would be appreciated.
I tried several things... mainly trying to compile and build the missing dll. I tried searching for the file online, but I can't find it for the life of me. I tried changing file types, of the configure file, which did nothing to benefit me as stated. All I want is for my solution to fully compile, but the required dependencies are not redistributed, nor are the versions required specified.
Thanks in advance.

Your basic problem seems to be that you are following Linux instructions when you are in fact running Windows. 'configure' is a common method for building software on Linux. Several Linux like systems exist for Windows, such as MSYS2, maybe you are supposed to be using one of those. But without seeing the instructions you are following it's hard to tell.

Not sure where you got your code from but this git repo https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus contains a folder called msvc14 which contains a Visual Studio project. My guess is that you are supposed to use that rather than a configure script.

@john trying this now, There is a sln file, it seems to have mostly compiled except an error missing 'QtGlobal' idk what that is, nor did what compiled produce the missing file 'log4cplusUD.dll'

@john As for your first comment... Are you suggesting I not run configure? I am reading the direct 'Generic' instructions provided in the 'INSTALL' file from downloading the latest (and previous) release from GitHub.

Yes that's what I'm suggesting. configure is a linux script, it makes no sense to run is on Windows.

This is a quote from the README On Windows, the primary build system is Visual Studio 2015 solution and projects (msvc14/log4cplus.sln).
